# Laravel groupBy groupBy need to show only last value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, group-by, sql-order-by

I have one table who has this values:

unidade_id, bloco_id, image_name and version.

To shrink my index view, I'm trying to show only the **last version** of image_name. But the problem is...
when I groupBy and orderBy this values, the result is always the first version.

Here is my controller:

```
$image_list = Imagem::orderBy('version', 'desc')       
    ->groupBy(['unidade_id', 'bloco_id', 'image_name'])  
    ->get();
```

My DB has this example values:

```
image_name: Windows10_SalaDeAula | version: 3.0
image_name: Windows10_SalaDeAula | version: 4.0
```

The result in my index is always the 3.0 version, but I need to show the last version only.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try the first group by only "image_name" and then order by "version"

Comment: I already tried this way... And don't worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add select option with max\min aggregation:

```
//add all necessary fields for selection
$image_list = Imagem::select(DB::raw('max(version) as version'))
    ->orderBy('version', 'desc')
    ->groupBy(['unidade_id', 'bloco_id', 'image_name'])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case `a result set` must first be `assembled` before  it is `ordered`

Use `groupBy` before `orderBy`

```
$image_list = groupBy(['unidade_id', 'bloco_id', 'image_name']) 
    ->orderBy('version', 'desc')       
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi Sehdev, I already try this, but didn't worked either. I need groupBy unidade_id and bloco_id because I have some places with the same image_name, in diferent bloco_id and unidade_id.
I really don't know why this is not working --'

Comment: I made a test changing versions, and only the first ID appear on view. Why orderBy before groupBy is not working?

Comment: In any case before a result set can be ordered it must first be assembled.

Answer (score 0):

Tks all, for the help.

Serguey It worked this way:

```
            $image_list = Imagem::select(DB::raw('max(version) as version'),
                DB::raw('max(id) as id'),
                'images.unidade_id as unidade_id',
                'images.bloco_id as bloco_id',
                'images.image_name as image_name')
            ->orderBy('version', 'desc')
            ->groupBy(['unidade_id', 'bloco_id', 'image_name'])
            ->get();
```